# TFS on mac OS X

Tags: git, macos, tfs

I'm front-end developer and I'm using Sublime on MAC OS El Capitan as my development tool. I'm changing my job and the new company has a TFS source control. I used TFS on Windows before but lately I was mainly on git. I hope to find the best way to use TFS on MAC.

So far I discovered several options:

1. GIT-TF - this seems like a very popular solution in 2012, regretfully all tutorials are for MAC OS Lion and I'm not sure if this is still the right way.
2. I read that you can enable GIT support in TFC project but as I'm not TFS administrator I'm not sure If this means to recreate the project or it's just an option that our admins can activate.
3. There is Sublime TFS plugin, have anyone tried it.
4. Perhaps there is more options but I can't figure out which one is the most appropriate for my case

Comment: You answered your own question: There are a bunch of options. Try them out and see if any of them work for you. If you have specific questions about one of those approaches, ask a question. As it stands, this question is off-topic because it's either too broad, or a tool recommendation.

Comment: Daniel, perhaps she doesn't have time to explore at least dozen of options besides her question is rather interesting. As it stands you're either too narrow or you like to hate too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get a better understanding of TFS. To asses TFS, the easiest thing to do it to create a free account for [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/).

The account is free for up to 5 people and you can create multiple repositories, using both Git or Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). Since the service is hosted for you, it doesn't matter which operating system you use, you just access a website.

To push code from MacOs, consider using VS Code, a multi-platform code editor. Many non Microsoft programmer IDEs have extensions for TFS, for example Eclipse. Any tool that interacts with Git can be used, and also the command line.

Note that TFS and Team Foundation Services are one and the same thing - one is offered on premise and one is hosted for you in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should still work.
2. No need to recreate the project but need to use at least TFS 2015 (surely the update 1) to be able to create git repository in the same project than an existing TFVC repository. But source code won't be shared.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you clarify it a little bit to me. If we setup TFS like that, Does this mean that will be able to work together some of us using tfs commands and some of us using git commands or git repository replaces tfs one

Comment: One tfs project can contain 1 TFVC repository and/or multiple git repositories. But there is no bridge or other sort of mapping between them. Tfs commands for TFVC repository and Git commands for the git repository. Add just git repositories if you already have a TFVC repository or the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

With so heavily bound to Windows systems on MAC I would go for Parallels. It's a virtual machine on which you can install Windows and have TFS. It's very sweet that you already have shared folders setuped. All check in/check out would be from there. You even can run the project from there, serving it on localhost and navigate it from MAC. And this is not everything. It has a coherence mode (I hope i wrote it right) which makes all windows windows to look like mac windows.